# removing URL from string using python's re

Tags: python, python-re

Using this to try to remove URLs from a string:

```
text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\.\/]+', '', text)
```

Unfortunately it works for simple URLs but not for complex ones.
So something like `http://www.example.com/somestuff.html` will be removed but something like `http://www.example.com/somestuff.html?query=python` etc. will just leave trailing bits behind.

I think I'm at the limits of my re knowledge so any help will be much appreciated.
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`r"https?:[^\s]+"`

Comment: Worked! Accepted. Thx. Just for my benefit, is this what's happening here: https? will match https or http. then match the :. then match start of string to unicode whitespace. finally + to match 1 or more repetitions.